# How can I split a string by some characters and not by a string made of these characters?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I split a string by `'-'` and `'>'` and **not** by `"->"`?

I would like to split the string below:

```
AAA-BBB->CCC>DDD
```

and get the result equal to:

```
{ "AAA", "BBB->CCC", "DDD" }
```

Comment: Not a duplicate. This is splitting by a single character delimiter, except when that character is part of a multi-part string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example uses a regular expression with lookahead and lookbehind rules to split a string based on '-' or '>' but not '->':

```
string input = "AAA-BBB->CCC>DDD";
var regex = new Regex("-(?!>)|(?<!-)>");
var split = regex.Split(input);
// split = { "AAA, "BBB->CCC", "DDD" }
```

Comment: I do feel this is slightly easier to read though: `Regex.Split(input, "(?!->)-|>(?<!->)");` It does the same.

Comment: Online regex testers may not handle this regex correctly because of the lookbehind rule, which is not supported by Javascript.  It will work correctly in C#, though.